# ImmutableJS for React Component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, immutability, immutable.js

So I decided to use ImmutableJS for working with Redux. Now I am wondering if it is convenient to use it for managing React Component `state`. I coded the following:

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const $$fixedLinks = Immutable.fromJS(this.props.fixedLinks);
    const $$dynamicLinks = Immutable.fromJS(this.props.dynamicLinks);

    this.state = {
      fixedLinks: this.addHrefs($$fixedLinks),
      dynamicLinks: this.addHrefs($$dynamicLinks),
    };
  }

  // Given a list of shape (id, name) we need to
  // add href for the links
  addHrefs = list => list.map(item => item.set('href', toUnderscore(item.get('name'))))

  render() {
    const fixed = this.state.fixedLinks.map(
      link => (
        <Link key={link.get('id')} href={`#${link.get('href')}`} title={link.get('name')} />
      ),
    );
    const dynamic = this.state.dynamicLinks.map(
      link => (
        <Link key={link.get('id')} href={`#${link.get('href')}`} title={link.get('name')} />
      ),
    );
    return (
      <Anchor>
        {fixed}
        {dynamic}
      </Anchor>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see `$$` indicates an immutable object. But then I want to add a new property to it with `addHrefs` and save it to `state`.

It is working like a charm. But it is a little akward the following:

```
<Link key={link.get('id')} href={`#${link.get('href')}`} title={link.get('name')} />
```

see? Using `get()` for getting values from the immutable object.

Now, some questions:

1. Is it a good idea (or approach) to use `ImmutableJS` for managing
   state in `React.Component`?
2. If I can use `ImmutableJS` for this purpose, should `this.state` be
   an immutable object? if so, how to deal with `this.setState()`?
3. If not so, I can't use `loadash` because it won't work with
   `ImmutableJS`, how can I deal with immutable states inside
   `React.Component`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is it a good idea (or approach) to use `ImmutableJS` for managing state in `React.Component`?

I can't see why it would be a **bad** idea. It's even mentioned in [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#using-immutable-data-structures).

> 2. If I can use `ImmutableJS` for this purpose, should `this.state` be an immutable object? if so, how to deal with `this.setState()`?

That's really up to you. There are benefits for having component state to be immutable (like being able to use [`PureComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) and get optimized performance).

I'm not sure what you mean with "deal with `this.setState()`". You continue to use it as usual: fetch your state, update it (thus obtaining a new object), call `setState` with the new object.

> 3. If not so, I can't use `loadash` because it won't work with `ImmutableJS`, how can I deal with immutable states inside `React.Component`?

You can call `const myState = this.state.toJS()` and use lodash with it. Just don't try to change the component's state changing something in `myState` because that won't work.

I hope this answers your questions, if I understood them correctly :)

Comment: Thank you really useful answer. I came to the react docs after posting, and there was the answer to "dealing with `setState`.